# Return all strings from column in a table. [MySQL; pymysql]

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

Is there a way to return all strings from a specific column in a MySQL database?

Note: I want to save those strings in a list, I'm also using pymysql.

Comment: Do you need the SQL query to get this, or how to get the result from your SQL query into a Python list?  Either way, can you provide *any* details as to a) what you want and b) what you have done to solve the problem?

Comment: I want to store the result from the query into a list to check if it contains a certain string. 
And to answer your second question, I have spent an hour looking through stack overflow and other forums to an answer to this (with some breaks for my sanity). 
I also tried to use "SHOW FIELDS FROM table" but that returns in a tabular format.

Comment: try running this query `data = pd.read_sql("SELECT cloumn_name FROM table_name",engine)`. This will give you data for that column only, then you can convert that to a list by `data_list = list(data['column_name'])`. now process `data_list` as per your need

Comment: If i put that in my IDE doesn't know what the `pd.read_sql` and `engine` are and says they are undefined. 
Edit: if i try to run it the `engine` part doens't work.

Answer (score 0):

Those are the steps you need to follow (in words as well since you do not provide any code either):

- Establish a connection with the database
- Create a cursor
- With the cursor you created execute a query which should be type of "SELECT column_that_you_want FROM table_you_want"
- The cursor now will hold the results.
- You can add the results in a list via a loop for example. Typically those results will be a one item tuple.